# Is it possible, with a dictionary, to specify part of the key, and allow the rest to be anything that the data type allows?

Tags: c#, dictionary

I have a list of people each with two sets of genes. The genes are designated by a string of the first few alphabet characters. A capital letter means it is a dominant allele, a lower case means recessive.

The first character of each set specifies the eye colour, and a combination of different alleles allows for different eye colours.

Is it possible to look up the combination of alleles, i.e. Ab, Ac or cA, and return the value for the existence of A.

My code so far is:

```
Dictionary<string, string> EyeColours = new Dictionary<string, string>
{ {"A","Blue"}, { "aa", "DarkBlue" }, { "bb", "Hazel" }, { "cc", "Gray" }, { "dd", "Amethyst" } };
```

and an example of the gene sets would be

```
{"AabAC", "aBAAd"}
```

I want the value "Blue" to be returned if the either of the first two chars is A, is there an efficient way to do this, or do I have to just brute force it?

Comment: Doesn't sound like a `Dictionary` will help here, you are probably fine just scanning a `List` to find the matches unless you have billions of them. Alternatively, sometimes it's worth precomputing all possible combinations and stuffing them into a lookup that can be a `Dictionary`.

Comment: Maybe a dictionary of dictionaries?

Comment: Could you split it into two dictionaries? One for single letter matches and one for two letter matches? Test the single letter one against each gene's first character and then test the two letter one against the combination of the two characters.

Comment: I may scan a list like you suggest, how many items would it become inefficient at? The list should only hit around 25 or so items, but if I want to add a new letter into the mix, it's not going to be very expandable. I like having two dictionaries, the nice thing being that you only need to look up in the dictionary for both under certain conditions

Comment: Your information seems contradictory - you say the first character specifies eye color, then show eye color mapped to two characters?

Answer (score 0):

Have a dictionary with all the different values as keys and the colour of the eyes as the value. Split your gene to either be a capital letter or your 2 lower case letters (co dominance). Then all you need is a simple System.Linq query:

```
string gene = <process it>;
List<string> result = new List<string>( );
result = dictionary.Where(kvp => kvp.Key.IndexOf(gene) >= 0).ToDictionary(kvp => kvp.Key, kvp => kvp.Value).Values.ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no efficient mechanism to look up all keys based on a substring. While making multiple lookups can work, it's also not very efficient.
One way to handle this efficiently would be to introduce an additional dictionary, which will contain the letter as a key, and map it to multiple keys in the other dictionary, all of which contain that letter.
Then, the lookup can be though of as follows:

1. Find the keys which contain the alleles in the first dictionary
2. Lookup each key in the second dictionary to find the genes

This, of course, will require to add items in both dictionaries.

Answer (score -1):

Dictionary has a ContainsKey(key) method:

From your examples:

```
{"AabAC", "aBAAd"}
```

You can pull your substrings out, I am assuming "A" or "Aa".  Then perform:

```
EyeColours.ContainsKey("A");
```

If the first on is successful, no need to do the second.  If not try with the second set.

Maybe have some handling to insert a new set if both fail.

From https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kw5aaea4(v=vs.110).aspx

"This method approaches an O(1) operation."

Or you can also try Dictionary.TryGetValue(key)

From https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb347013(v=vs.110).aspx

"This method approaches an O(1) operation."

Both are efficient, and both are built into dictionary.

```
string eyeColorSet1 = gene.Substring(0, 1)
```

and

```
string eyeColorSet2 = gene.Substring(0, 2)
```

To get your leading alleles to check is not difficult or expensive either.

I would put all of this into its own method named

```
string GetEyeColour(string geneSequence)
```

or something to that effect.  Get your test substrings, search the dictionary, add new if that's something you want to handle.

Given the efficiency of the dictionary methods, keeping only 1 collection and checking it for 2 values is going to be easier to manage and maintain than 2 collections.  This also holds true if you are going to check for 3 values, ie "A", "a", or "Aa", from your example set.

Comment: A down vote with no comment?  What is this answer leaving out?